# Sonar scanner report file with taskId and analysisId

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

### What I have for JAVA

I am using Jenkins as my CI/CD server and I created a Jenkinsfile for my JAVA project and for the scanning and quality I am using the maven sonar plugin. The `mvn sonar:sonar` command generate a file at target/sonar/report-task.txt. The file contains information related with the scanning process and using that information I am able to call the SonarQube REST API with the taskId generated and then I am able to call the REST API using analysisId and decide if the pipeline is broken based on the quality conditions.

### What I want for Javascript (any other type of project)

I am trying to do something similar for a Javascript project but this time and using the sonar-scanner from command line but I realized that there is not file generated as report-task.txt ( I believe this file is only generated by maven sonar-plugin). So I will like to know if there is a way to generate that kind of information.

I really need the taskId value in order to do dynamically calls to SonarQube REST API once the scanner process has started.

Comment: One question here: Is your sonar scan is successful for Javascript project ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Jenkinsfile there's no need to do this manually. From [the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline)

```
node {
  stage('SCM') {
    git 'https://github.com/foo/bar.git'
  }
  stage('SonarQube analysis') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('My SonarQube Server') {
      sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar'
    } // SonarQube taskId is automatically attached to the pipeline context
  }
}

// No need to occupy a node
stage("Quality Gate"){
  timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
    def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
    if (qg.status != 'OK') {
      error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
    }
  }
}
```

If you're not using Maven to build and analyze, then just sub-in the correct commands as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer bath only apply for java project but what happen if I want to use the same process for Javascript application or any other kind. What I am trying to do is using Openshift Container with the SonarRunner (Scanner Installed) and using the properties files or command line to customize the project properties.

Comment: See my addition @Robert

Answer (score 0):

The file contains information related with the scanning process is:
.scannerwork/report-task.txt